# Uniqueness of gzip'ed strings

Tags: c#, string, compression, gzip, unique

Here's my compression algorith, taken from somewhere here on SO :

```
 var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
 using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
 {
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    {
       using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
       {
          msi.CopyTo(gs);
       }
       return Convert.ToBase64String(mso.ToArray());
    }
 }
```

Given a set of unique strings, can I be completely sure that the output strings will be unique too?

Comment: I would certainly hope so. If GZip has collisions in its compression algorithm, it would be hard to guarantee getting the right data back when decompressed.

Comment: That's how I felt... but I don't know a **** about compression algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The output of any reversible algorithm must be unique for each unique input.  Think about it this way: If two inputs produced the same output, then how could you ever unzip it?

With that said: Are you trying to use this as a way to hash data?  If so, this is probably a very inefficient way to do it.  If you aren't really compressing the data, don't use a compression algorithm.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a bunch of json objects that are the parameters to retreive a certain set of data. I am thinking of using the json as key to cache the data. I'm not sure if it's worth compressing the key.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  So you need the key for a lookup, but the JSON seems awfully big to use as a key.  My guess is that compressing the JSON then converting it to Base64 will be slower than just using the JSON directly as a key to a hash table.  Probably try it before investing too much time in the compression approach.  Good luck!